# How to get a model using its related models

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a peer to peer chat,

I have three models, The ChatMessage, chat and the user model, the chat and user model have a many to many relationship, I have created a pivot table 'chat_user', and defined a belongToMany on both models.

when a user initiates a chat, it receives the userId and the Id of the receiver, here is the function:

```
 public function InitSingleChat(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $receiver = User::findOrFail($request->receiver_id);
    if ($user) {
        if ($receiver) {
            $chat = Chat::find([$user -> id, $receiver -> id])->first();
            if ($chat) {
                return response()->json(['channel' => "private-chat-" . $chat->id, 'chat' => $chat]);
            } else {
                $chat = new Chat();
                $chat -> save();
                $chat -> users() -> attach($user);
                $chat -> users() -> attach($receiver);
                return response()->json(['channel' => "private-chat-" . $chat->id, 'chat' => $chat]);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json('Receiver not found', 404);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json('You are not signed in', 401);
    }
}
```

The idea is to first find if the two user id have a Chat model in common, if not, it create a new chat and attach both users to a single chat, and return the chat id, else it returns the chat id.

this block  `$chat = Chat::find([$user -> id, $receiver -> id])->first();` however always returns all chat that id related to the first userId i.e ($user -> id).

What i actually wanted is to find chat that have the exact two userIds in its collection, or create a new one if it doesn't exist.

i also tried `$chat = Chat::whereIn('id', [$user -> id,$receiver -> id])->get()` This worked like an Or statement, while need an AND statement

in pseudo code what i am tring to get is this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the chat via the relation:

```
$chat = Chat::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user, $receiver) {
    return $query->whereIn('id', [$user->id, $receiver->id]);
})->get()->first();
```

However, there is a fundamental problem with your data structure. You have no way of differentiating between a user and a receiver in your database. Instead you should be passing the chat id to the request and you could just do something as simple as:

```
$chat = Chat::find($request->id);
```

See docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

> When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, imagine you want to retrieve all blog posts that have at least one comment. To do so, you may pass the name of the relationship to the `has` and `orHas` methods.

> If you need even more power, you may use the `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` methods to put "where" conditions on your `has` queries. These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment

Comment: Thank ypu @purgatory for your answer, However i am getting undefined $user when i replaces your code snippet with the  $chat = Chat::find([$user -> id, $receiver -> id])->first();

Comment: @Nathaniel I have edited the code to remove the error. It is just an example for using ‘whereHas’ though. Your table structure makes it impossible to reliably get the chat you want just using user and receiver id. see paragraph after code.

Comment: yeah thanks... i don't really want to separate the receiver from the user, the user is the sender,, the table can changer and the receiver can become the sender, i don't want it to create a new chat in this case. Is there another approach you can suggest? Thanks again

Comment: All I can suggest is read some blog posts/articles about creating a chat application there are plenty out there and you can take some inspiration from how they have structured their data. For example https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel